# Pandas Series - Count rows between column values

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas series:

```
    2004-01-01    0
    2004-01-02    0
    2004-01-03    0
    2004-01-04    0
    2004-01-05    1
    2004-01-06    0
    2004-01-07    0
    2004-01-08    3
    2004-01-09    0
    2004-01-10    2
    2004-01-11    0
```

I want to add,efficiently, a column which count the number of rows between the actual row and the next row with a number greater than 0.

In this case it would be:

```
    2004-01-01    0     3
    2004-01-02    0     2
    2004-01-03    0     1
    2004-01-04    0     0
    2004-01-05    1     2
    2004-01-06    0     1
    2004-01-07    0     0
    2004-01-08    3     1
    2004-01-09    0     0
    2004-01-10    2     ...
    2004-01-11    0     ...
```

The first number of the new column is 3 because there are 3 rows between this row and the next one with something different to 0 on the first column, and so on.

An efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby(df.A.gt(0).cumsum()).cumcount(ascending=False)
print (df)
            A  B
2004-01-01  0  3
2004-01-02  0  2
2004-01-03  0  1
2004-01-04  0  0
2004-01-05  1  2
2004-01-06  0  1
2004-01-07  0  0
2004-01-08  3  1
2004-01-09  0  0
2004-01-10  2  1
2004-01-11  0  0
```

**Explanation**:

First compare column by [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) `>` for boolean mask:

```
print (df.A.gt(0))
2004-01-01    False
2004-01-02    False
2004-01-03    False
2004-01-04    False
2004-01-05     True
2004-01-06    False
2004-01-07    False
2004-01-08     True
2004-01-09    False
2004-01-10     True
2004-01-11    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Then use [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for cumulative `sum`:

```
print (df.A.gt(0).cumsum())
2004-01-01    0
2004-01-02    0
2004-01-03    0
2004-01-04    0
2004-01-05    1
2004-01-06    1
2004-01-07    1
2004-01-08    2
2004-01-09    2
2004-01-10    3
2004-01-11    3
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Last use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False` for descending order in counter:

```
print (df.groupby(df.A.gt(0).cumsum()).cumcount(ascending=False))
2004-01-01    3
2004-01-02    2
2004-01-03    1
2004-01-04    0
2004-01-05    2
2004-01-06    1
2004-01-07    0
2004-01-08    1
2004-01-09    0
2004-01-10    1
2004-01-11    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That's what i needed. Thanks!